# CI upload file demo not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter 2.2.6 for my server (I am a newbie in CI), when I tried to make the upload file demo work, but nothing happened when I clicked on the submit button.

Here is the user guide that I followed:

[File Uploading Class](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/file_uploading.html)

the view file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo $error;?>

<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="upload" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the controller:

```
<?php
class Upload extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct ();
        $this->load->helper ( array (
                'form',
                'url' 
        ) );
    }
    function index() {
        echo CI_VERSION;

        $this->load->view ( 'upload_form', array (
                'error' => ' ' 
        ) );
    }

    function do_upload() {
        $config ['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config ['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config ['max_size'] = '100';
        $config ['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config ['max_height'] = '768';

        $this->load->library ( 'upload', $config );

        echo "step 1";

        if (! $this->upload->do_upload ()) {
            echo "step 2";

            $error = array (
                    'error' => $this->upload->display_errors () 
            );

            $this->load->view ( 'upload_form', $error );
        } else {
            echo "step 3";

            $data = array (
                    'upload_data' => $this->upload->data () 
            );

            $this->load->view ( 'upload_success', $data );
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I can see the browse and submit button, after I select a file, the file name is correctly displayed but when I click on submit, nothing happens, it looks like that the submit click is not handled.

As you can see, I set 3 echo "step ." to follow the flow, but none of them get printed, I don't know why.

Could anyone help? please explain me the logic behind that button click handling.

Comment: can you check $_FILES array is posted in controller function ?

Comment: @RanjeetSingh, how can I check that?
function do_upload is not called at all, there seems to be a problem in 
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>

Comment: check form-url using firebug ? or try to write static url that submit form on do_upload ?

Comment: @RanjeetSingh, the form is:

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="http://::1/upload/do_upload">
<input type="file" size="20" name="userfile">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>

Comment: ok, I got it, I removed the above mentioned form_open_multipart and add directly the url, it works now!
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the action url is not correct.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="http://::1/upload/do_upload"> 
    <input type="file" size="20" name="userfile"> <br> <br>
     <input type="submit" value="upload">
 </form>
```

This seems to be related to what I have done to remove the index.php in the website url, 
I have

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

and that made the action url become

```
http://::1/upload/do_upload
```

which made the demo not work, the solution is to add manually the correct action url.